# How to get the value of the Html element near to the element which triggers the Event

Tags: jquery, html, events

I am using the HTML code as follows:

```
     <label style="display:inline;">Information</label>
     <a id="eventtrigger" >Click</a>
```

and jquery as follows:

```
    $("#eventtrigger").click(function(event){
      //event handling process
      });
```

I want to get the value of the label near to the element triggers event.
That means i should get the value  "**Infomation**" inside jquery event handlng process "**without using any specific selectors such as ID or Class**".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [**prev**](http://api.jquery.com/prev/), to get the previous element.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/nRgkN/)**

```
 $("#eventtrigger").click(function(event){
     alert($(this).prev().text());
  });
```

or looking specifically for previous label

```
$("#eventtrigger").click(function(event){
     alert($(this).prev('label').text());
});
```

Comment: I would simply use `.prev` instead of `.prev('label')`

Comment: @Vega what if there's something between the link and the label?  There isn't in this example, but there may be in the real world.

Comment: @Archer Well if the layout is such then you don't need to an extra check right?

Comment: @Vega "if the layout is such" - my point exactly.  Code for the future, not for the example.

Comment: Is it possible to get the element under the previous parent

Comment: @Aravind - so far this has had nothing to do with parent elements, only the previous label.  What do you mean?

Comment: @Archer mm true.. but in my opinion `.prev([selector])` is least used because the layout is mostly fixed but it could be just me.

Comment: @Vega - I totally understand what you're saying.  I work mostly with data driven, dynamic websites (asp.net) for multiple customers (over 40 versions of the same core package).  I always code with the "what if" in mind.  If you don't need to do that then you can get away with assumptions like that, but in my line of work I can't.  I'm just used to coding defensively.

Comment: @Archer My question is i got a DIV in place of label  in the above code..The DIV containes 3  elements with different ID..Is it possible to get the value of that.

Comment: Your question is not clear but it seems possible. If you put a new question you will get answer. Or send explain more details here.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `.prev()`

```
$("#eventtrigger").click(function(event){
     $(this).prev('label').text();
 });
```

You can also use the `.siblings()` method

```
 $("#eventtrigger").click(function(event){
     alert($(this).siblings('label').text());
  });​
```

**[Check FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/JKtrs/)**

Answer (score 1):

If your HTML will always look like that, then go with @Adil's method.  However, if you need it to be more dynamic, use [.siblings()](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) and simply grab the [.first()](http://api.jquery.com/first/) one and that will be the "closest".

For instance you could consider something like:

```
//  The following will grab the closest label to any a tag clicked on
$("a").on("click", function(e) {
    var closest = $(this).siblings("label").first();
    console.log(closest);
}):
```

However, I *think* this will grab the first one *after* if there is a label on **each** side of it, if that is undesirable and you want the first one previously (for instance, you might have multiple labels and p tags before an a tag), You need something beyond [.prev()](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) as [.prev()](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) will only grab the FIRST element before the a tag. In that case, use [.prevAll()](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/) combined with [.first()](http://api.jquery.com/first/) to get the first label mentioned before the a tag.

As such:

```
$("a").on("click", function(e) {
    var closest = $(this).prevAll("label").first();
    console.log(closest);
}):
```

And of course for the opposite case you can use [.nextAll()](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/)

```
$("a").on("click", function(e) {
    var closest = $(this).nextAll("label").first();
    console.log(closest);
}):
```